# How to generate the Organizer field with DDay.iCal?

Tags: c#, icalendar, dday

I am using the C# library DDay.iCal and trying to produce the ORGANIZER field as defined in IETF RFC 2445:

```
ORGANIZER;CN=John Smith:MAILTO:jsmith@host1.com
```

A simple question: how can I do this? I have already tried several alternatives with no success: there is always something wrong with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this myself. This was pretty obvious after studying RFC 2445 (or 5545) more closely:

```
iCalendar iCal = new iCalendar();
Event ev = iCal.Create<Event>();

ev.Organizer = new Organizer("MAILTO:jsmith@host1.com");
ev.Organizer.CommonName = "John Smith";
```

Ok, the result is not exactly the same:

```
ORGANIZER;CN="John Smith":MAILTO:jsmith@host1.com
```

However, MS Outlook accepts this format and this is what I was looking after.